# JavaSerializer - Error serializing object -> wicket

Tags: java, wicket

I have a home page(BasePage) with tabs, everything works fine,I don't have any problem with the functionality of my code. But this exception annoys me and I want to get rid of it. I looked at this

[Error serializing object class - when running Wicket and GAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26691901/error-serializing-object-class-when-running-wicket-and-gae)

and this

[Wicket: how to get rid of WicketNotSerializableException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16855252/wicket-how-to-get-rid-of-wicketnotserializableexception)

but I didn't manage to solve my problem. Can anyone help me?

```
public class BasePage extends WebPage {
    public static final String PATH = "base";

    public BasePage() {
        final List tabs = new ArrayList<>();

        //add Search Item Tab
        tabs.add(new AbstractTab(new Model<>("Search Item")) {
            @Override
            public WebMarkupContainer getPanel(String s) {
                return new SearchItem(s);
            }
        });

        //add Search Domain Tab
        tabs.add(new AbstractTab(new Model<>("Search Domain")) {
            @Override
            public WebMarkupContainer getPanel(String s) {
                return new SearchDomain(s);
            }
        });

        AjaxTabbedPanel ajaxTabbedPanel = new AjaxTabbedPanel("tabs", tabs);

        add(new AjaxTabbedPanel("tabs", tabs));
    }
}
```

stacktrace:

```
2015-08-28 11:39:48,456 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] ERROR org.apache.wicket.serialize.java.JavaSerializer - Error serializing object class com.ui.homepage.BasePage [object=[Page class = com.ui.homepage.BasePage, id = 0, render count = 1]]
org.apache.wicket.core.util.objects.checker.CheckingObjectOutputStream$ObjectCheckException: The object type is not Serializable!
A problem occurred while checking object with type: com.persistence.RequestEntityDAOExtra
Field hierarchy is:
  0 [class=com.ui.homepage.BasePage, path=0]
    private java.lang.Object org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.children [class=org.apache.wicket.extensions.ajax.markup.html.tabs.AjaxTabbedPanel, path=0:tabs]
      private java.lang.Object org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.children [class=[Ljava.lang.Object;]
        private org.apache.wicket.markup.html.link.PopupSettings org.apache.wicket.markup.html.link.Link.popupSettings[1] [class=com.searchpages.SearchItem, path=0:tabs:panel]
          private java.lang.Object org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.children [class=[Ljava.lang.Object;]
            private java.lang.Object org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.children[1] [class=org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form, path=0:tabs:panel:searchForm]
              private java.lang.Object org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.children [class=[Ljava.lang.Object;]
                private java.lang.Object org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.children[0] [class=org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebMarkupContainer, path=0:tabs:panel:searchForm:searchInput]
                  private java.lang.Object org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.children [class=[Ljava.lang.Object;]
                    private java.lang.Object org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.children[0] [class=org.apache.wicket.extensions.ajax.markup.html.autocomplete.AutoCompleteTextField, path=0:tabs:panel:searchForm:searchInput:callerId]
                      final com.persistence.RequestEntityDAOExtra com.ui.searchpages.SearchItem$1.val$requestEntityDAOExtra [class=com.persistence.RequestEntityDAOExtra] <----- field that is causing the problem
```

UPDATE:
I found the problem but I can't understand why it works

Before:

```
final RequestEntityDAOExtra requestEntityDAOExtra =
        ((MyApp) getApplication()).getRequestEntityDAOExtra();

//callerId input
final AutoCompleteTextField<String> callerInput = new AutoCompleteTextField<String>("callerId", new Model<String>(),
        autoCompleteSettings) {
    @Override
    protected Iterator getChoices(String callerId) {
        return requestEntityDAOExtra.getEntitiesByCallerId(callerId).iterator();
    }
};
```

After:

```
final AutoCompleteTextField<String> callerInput = new AutoCompleteTextField<String>("callerId", new Model<String>(),
        autoCompleteSettings) {
    @Override
    protected Iterator getChoices(String callerId) {
        final RequestEntityDAOExtra requestEntityDAOExtra =
                ((MyApp) getApplication()).getRequestEntityDAOExtra();
        return requestEntityDAOExtra.getEntitiesByCallerId(callerId).iterator();
    }
};
```

If I declare my dao object inside the method the exception doesn't exist anymore. But why?

Comment: Could you provide us with the full stacktrace? From this code it looks like only ``List tabs`` will be serialized.

Comment: I added the stacktrace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it seems like `RequestEntityDAOExtra` is not `Serializable`. I can't really say why not or if it should be `Serializable` because it's highly depending on your application.

In your first case your declaring:

```
final RequestEntityDAOExtra requestEntityDAOExtra =
    ((MyApp) getApplication()).getRequestEntityDAOExtra();
```

During the serialization this will be treated the same as any member variable since it needs to be restored whenever an anonymous inner class is executed.
My suggestion is to be very careful when declaring variables as `final` when working in Wicket context. For my projects I'm only allowing implementations of `IModel` to be declared as final (plus any Wicket component obviously).

Your second approach works because the `RequestEntityDAOExtra` will not be serialized with the `Panel` but freshly requested from your `Application` each time.

Comment: When it was declared outside the method i get a compiling error if the member in not declared final because it is accessed from an inner class. Thanks for answering!

Comment: Yeah of course. Declaring a variable final can be seen as declaring it as a class variable (with all the serialization implications at least). Please note that in java 8 you'll no longer need to declare a variable as final to access it in an inner class. But the problems with the serialization will (most likely, haven't tested it yet) perist.